# How to change the style of the checkbox in TCPDF?

Tags: javascript, php, adobe, tcpdf, acrobat

I use TCPDF method to Create a checkbox for make a PDF file, and the displayed effect is not what I want:

`$pdf->CheckBox('checkbox1', 5, true, array(), array(), '1',);`

I check TCPDF.PHP get this info:

*@param $prop (array) javascript field properties. Possible values are described on official Javascript for Acrobat API reference.*

And I read this : "https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf"

*Allows the user to set the glyph style of a check box or radio button. The glyph style is the graphic used to indicate that the item has been selected. The style values are associated with keywords as follows.*

*Style Keyword*

*check style.ch*

*cross style.cr*

*diamond style.di*

How to write style $pron array()?

I try this but not work:

`$pdf->CheckBox('checkbox1', 5, true, array('style' => 'style.ci'), array(), '1',);`